# como trabajar con promesas dentro de una transacción mysql y no con devoluciones de llamada?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, promesas, transacciones, async-await

Me explico mejor:

Ya se que hay un modulo mysql que trabaja con promesas, pero comencé a trabajar con mysql básico (el que trabaja con devoluciones de llamadas) y por eso no puedo cambiar a estas alturas. Así que leí que se node.js tiene el modulo Util con el que se pueden convertir callbacks a promesas a través de `util.promisify` pero no me esta funcionando.

Lo que quiero hacer es trabajar con async/await usando transacciones. Quiero lograr algo como esto:

```js
const resendLink= async (email)=> {
            try {
                console.log('\nEjecutando resendLink...\n')
                const connection= await util.promisify(db.getConnection)
                console.log('\nResultado de db.getConnection.. \n',connection)
                const result= await util.promisify(connection.beginTransaction)
                
                //llamadas a métodos para realizar operaciones en la base de datos

               //y por último realizar el commit y finalizar la conexión
               //await util.promisify(connection.commit())
               //await util.promisify(connection.release())                  

            } catch(e) {
                console.log('\n\nEjecutando rollback...:',e)
                await util.promisify(connection.rollback())
                throw(e)
            }
}
```

pero tengo unos problemas, cuándo se va a ejecutar esta línea `const result= await util.promisify(connection.beginTransaction)`  me arroja el siguiente error: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argumen t must be of type Function. Received type undefined` . Así que antes de llegar a ese línea coloqué un console.log del resultado de `db.getConnection` y me muestra esto:

```js
 function fn(...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      original.call(this, ...args, (err, ...values) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        if (argumentNames !== undefined && values.length > 1) {
          const obj = {};
          for (var i = 0; i < argumentNames.length; i++)
            obj[argumentNames[i]] = values[i];
          resolve(obj);
        } else {
          resolve(values[0]);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

creo que ese no debería ser el resultado de `db.getConnection`

Es importante aclarar que estoy trabajando con un pool de conexiones, y ya he trabajado con trasacciones, solo que las he usado normal, con devoluciones de llamada.

Acá dejo la condiguración del pool por si sirve de algo:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const mysql = require('mysql');


const pool = mysql.createPool ( { 
  host: process.env.DB_HOST, 
  user: process.env.DB_USER, 
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT, 
  database: process.env.DB_NAME 
} ) ;

module.exports.pool = pool;
```

No encuentro como hacer poder convertir las transacciones a promesas y así poder tranajar con async/await. Que estoy haciendo mal? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

[ SOLUCIÓN ]

Lo que trataba de hacer exactamente era poder usar
promesas y resolverlas con async/await dentro de una transacción debido a que, para trabajar con transacciones se necesitan muchas callbacks, una para poder obtener la conexión, otra para iniciar la transacción, una para cada consulta/operación que se vaya a realizar en la Base de datos, además de las que se usan para el rollback y el commit. A continuación, dejo la solución que pude implementar a mi problema.

Mi archivo donde configuro mi base de datos quedó así:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const util = require('util');



const pool = mysql.createPool ( { 
  host: process.env.DB_HOST, 
  user: process.env.DB_USER, 
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT, 
  database: process.env.DB_NAME 
} ) ;

const getConnection= ()=> {
    return util.promisify(pool.getConnection).call(pool) //aquí usé call en vez de bind para hacer el return de una vez, si usaba el bind
    //tenía que primero hacer el bind, guardar eso en una variable y luego hacer el return de esa variable, ya que la diferencia entre bind y call
    // es que call llama inmediatamente a la función y bind crea una copia de la función pero no la llama, hay que llamar en una siguiente línea.
}


const beginTransaction= (connection)=> { 
    return util.promisify(connection.beginTransaction).call(connection); 
}

const rollback= (connection)=> {
    console.log('\n\nEjecutando Rollback...\n\n')
    return util.promisify(connection.rollback).call(connection)
}

const commit= (connection)=> {
    return util.promisify(connection.commit).call(connection)
}

// const release= (connection)=> {
//  return util.promisify(connection.release).call(connection)
// }

module.exports = {
    pool: pool,
    getConnection: getConnection,
    // query: query
    beginTransaction: beginTransaction,
    rollback: rollback,
    commit: commit,
}
```

Aquí lo que se hace es crear una funcion para llamar a cada método necesario para usar las trasacciones (getConnection,beginTransaction,rollback y commit), estos métodos originalmente en el paquete Mysql original trabajan con call backs, como yo lo que quería era trabajar con promesas, la forma de transformarlo a una promesa es usando util.promisify de node.js y usamos el método .call para pasar que el contexto de la función a llamar sea igual al contexto de la conexión (parametro connection) en este caso.

En este punto es donde no quedé 100% claro. No bastaba con hacer por ejemplo la llamada para el beginTransaction así: `connection.beginTransaction` al utilizar ese connection. (connection punto) antes del beginTransaction no se estaría como pasando ese connection (que es el resultado de getConnection) a la función beginTransaction? bueno... ahi es donde no me siento 100% claro, si alguien pudiera aclararme esta duda estaría enormemente agradecido.

Bueno... sigo con el resto, el método resendLink que era donde tenía mi transacción quedó así:

```js
    const resendLink= async (email)=> { //´se envia el link al correo (esta ´funcion se llama cuándo el link para validar la cta ha vencido)
            try {
                console.log('\nEjecutando resendLink...\n')
                connection= await db.getConnection(); 
                console.log('Connection: ',connection)
                result= await db.beginTransaction(connection);
                console.log('\n\nResultado de beginTransaction.. \n',result)
                /* // FORMA 1 usando CALL
                const query= util.promisify(connection.query)
                userInfo= await query.call(connection,'select id_cuenta from cuenta where id_usuario= 339');
                //***************************
                FORMA 2 usando BIND
                const query= util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection)  */
                userInfo= await getUserInfoByEmail(email,connection) //<--- llamadas a funciones para realizar operaciones en la Base de Datos
                console.log('\n\n\nMostrando userInfo---> '+userInfo[0].id_usuario)
                accountInfo= await getAccountIdByUserId(userInfo[0].id_usuario,connection) //<--- llamadas a funciones para realizar operaciones en la Base de Datos
                console.log('\nMostrando accountInfo[0].id_cuenta:'+accountInfo[0].id_cuenta)
                const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(); 
                const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(userInfo[0].nombres+accountInfo[0].id_cuenta,salt); 
                await updateActivationLink(hash,accountInfo[0].id_cuenta,connection)  //<--- llamadas a funciones para realizar operaciones en la Base de Datos
                mailData = {
                    names: userInfo.nombres, email: userInfo.correo, subject: 'Registro de Usuario',
                    msg: 'Te has registrado en nuestra página, el link para verificar tu cuenta es: ', 
                    link: process.env.HOST_PATH_FRONT+'activateAccount/?hash='+hash+'&id='+accountInfo[0].id_cuenta, linkName: 'Activar Tu Cuenta'
                }                   
                result= await sendEmail(mailData)  //<--- llamadas a funciones para realizar operaciones en la Base de Datos
                await db.commit(connection);
                connection.release();
                return({emailFound: true})          
            } catch(e) {
                connection.release();
                console.log('\n\nEjecutando rollback...:',e)
                await db.rollback(connection)
                throw(e)
            }
    }
```

Eso era lo que quería lograr, usar async/await dentro de la transacción, básicamente para poder que las funciones que realizan operaciones en la BD (getUserInfoByEmail, updateActivationLink, etc...) fueran reusables y las pudiera usar donde no uso transacciones sino simples operaciones y no tener que colocar cada consulta así por ejemplo:  `connection.query('update cuenta set link_cambio_clave= ?, link_cambio_clave_expiracion= ? WHERE id_usuario= ?', [hash, moment().add(1,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD'), data.userId], function(err, rows) {`

Si se fijan, el único método que no se "promisificó" fué  `release()` esto es por que ese método no usa callbacks, se ejecuta así: `release()` simplemente.

Por último, lo que hice para reusar esas funciones que realizan las operaciones en la Bd en otra parte donde no se necesario usar transacciones lo que hice fue esto:

```js
    const getAccountIdByUserId= (userId,connection=false)=> { //se obtiene id de la cuenta a través del id del usuario
    //si connection es false quiere decir que esta funcion se llamo solo con 1 argumento (userID) y esto solo ocurre en las operaciones 
    //que no hacen uso de uso de una transaccion. En las transacciones si se pasa el parametro #2 (connection) para usarlo en el bind (mas abajo)
        if(!connection){
            console.log('\n\nConnection es Falseeeeeeee\n\n')
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {  // se retorna una promesa para las operaciones que no son una tramsaccion
                db.pool.query('select id_cuenta from cuenta where id_usuario= ?', [userId], (error,rows)=> {
                    return error? reject(error): resolve(rows);
                } )
            })
        }else{
            console.log('\n\n¡ Connection Tiene Un Valorrr !\n\n')
            //se usa la connection para hacer que el "this" de la funcion connection.query haga referencia al "this" del parametro "connection"
            //luego se retorna en forma de promesa usando "util.promisify"
            const query= util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection)
            //acá es donde se llama a connection.query como tal y se le pasan los parametros que normalmente recibe (la consulta)
            return query('select id_cuenta from cuenta where id_usuario= ?', [userId])          
        }

    }
```

En ese método se reciben 3 parametros, el último es la conexión (connection) que se pasa desde la transacción, si este parámetro no se pasa quiere decir que no lo estoy llamando desde una transacción y entonces toma un valor booleano false, y entonces ejecuto la consulta normal (esto pasa en casos donde no estoy llamando al método desde una transacción, puede ser por ejemplo casos en los que no se altera la integridad de la BD). Bueno... espero ayudar con esto a alguien que lo necesite como yo.

Saludos de nuevo!